# Python 3 xml parsing and printing problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have a sample xml file as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!--Created with JFLAP 7.1.--><structure>&#13;
    <type>fa</type>&#13;
    <automaton>&#13;
        <!--The list of states.-->&#13;
        <state id="0" name="q1">&#13;
            <x>104.0</x>&#13;
            <y>149.0</y>&#13;
            <initial/>&#13;
        </state>&#13;
        <state id="1" name="q2">&#13;
            <x>210.0</x>&#13;
            <y>153.0</y>&#13;
            <final/>&#13;
        </state>&#13;
        <state id="2" name="q3">&#13;
            <x>292.0</x>&#13;
            <y>155.0</y>&#13;
        </state>&#13;
        <!--The list of transitions.-->&#13;
        <transition>&#13;
            <from>0</from>&#13;
            <to>0</to>&#13;
            <read>0</read>&#13;
        </transition>&#13;
        <transition>&#13;
            <from>1</from>&#13;
            <to>1</to>&#13;
            <read>1</read>&#13;
        </transition>&#13;
        <transition>&#13;
            <from>0</from>&#13;
            <to>1</to>&#13;
            <read>1</read>&#13;
        </transition>&#13;
        <transition>&#13;
            <from>2</from>&#13;
            <to>1</to>&#13;
            <read>0</read>&#13;
        </transition>&#13;
        <transition>&#13;
            <from>1</from>&#13;
            <to>2</to>&#13;
            <read>0</read>&#13;
        </transition>&#13;
        <transition>&#13;
            <from>2</from>&#13;
            <to>1</to>&#13;
            <read>1</read>&#13;
        </transition>&#13;
    </automaton>&#13;
</structure>
```

I'm trying to print all the `name` attributes of the `state` tag except `id`
So far here is my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for automaton in root.findall('automaton'):
    state = automaton.find('state')
    state_name = state.get('name')
    print(state_name)
```

My Current output:

```
q1
```

My Expected output:

```
q1
q2
q3
```

I'm confused because isn't the `for` loop in my code would print all the `name` attributes? Where did I do wrong and how do I fix it? Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

You are lacking another `findall` in your code. There are multiple `state` tags.

See this code below. (I substituted a text io buffer for a file.)

```
﻿    xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!--Created with JFLAP 7.1.--><structure>&#13;
    <type>fa</type>&#13;
    <automaton>&#13;
        <!--The list of states.-->&#13;
        <state id="0" name="q1">&#13;
            <x>104.0</x>&#13;
            <y>149.0</y>&#13;
            <initial/>&#13;
        </state>&#13;
        <state id="1" name="q2">&#13;
            <x>210.0</x>&#13;
            <y>153.0</y>&#13;
            <final/>&#13;
        </state>&#13;
        <state id="2" name="q3">&#13;
            <x>292.0</x>&#13;
            <y>155.0</y>&#13;
        </state>&#13;
        <!--The list of transitions.-->&#13;
        <transition>&#13;
            <from>0</from>&#13;
            <to>0</to>&#13;
            <read>0</read>&#13;
        </transition>&#13;
        <transition>&#13;
            <from>1</from>&#13;
            <to>1</to>&#13;
            <read>1</read>&#13;
        </transition>&#13;
        <transition>&#13;
            <from>0</from>&#13;
            <to>1</to>&#13;
            <read>1</read>&#13;
        </transition>&#13;
        <transition>&#13;
            <from>2</from>&#13;
            <to>1</to>&#13;
            <read>0</read>&#13;
        </transition>&#13;
        <transition>&#13;
            <from>1</from>&#13;
            <to>2</to>&#13;
            <read>0</read>&#13;
        </transition>&#13;
        <transition>&#13;
            <from>2</from>&#13;
            <to>1</to>&#13;
            <read>1</read>&#13;
        </transition>&#13;
    </automaton>&#13;
</structure>"""


from io import StringIO
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_file = StringIO(xml)
tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
root = tree.getroot()
for automaton in root.findall('automaton'):
    for state in automaton.findall('state'): # find all the 'state' tags
        state_name = state.get('name')
        print(state_name)
```

OUTPUT:

```
q1
q2
q3
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply I understand it now, I'm learning about Python so that this kind of mistake happens to me all the time.

Comment: You're welcome. Kindly accept the answer and give it an up-vote if it helped you out. Thank you.